# Xamarin UI Test - testing other pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

Sorry, a newbie when it comes to UITest. I am just thinking on how to test other pages with UITest? By default, UITest creates a Tests class and can be used for your first page, but how do I do it with other pages? Would it be the same just making sure each AutomationId is correct? Thanks!

Comment: You "exercise" the app just as the user would.  If you have other pages/screens in your app, how do the users get to those(?), assumably by filling out some fields and touching/clicking a button, or selecting an item in a list view, etc... you would mimic those user actions in your test.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you, I am very well aware of those, but what I want to know is how should I do it using UITest. I have tried it with UnitTesting ViewModels, but I am clueless with UITest when navigating or doing it with other pages.

Comment: Not sure what you mean then, if the user touches a button to go to another page, then have your UITest touch that button and test that the new page appears via queries that test if the correct information is on that page based upon the test actions that took you to get to that page.

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry if it was not clear, do I need multiple test classes to initiate the tests like a Unit Test can do? If yes, how would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: You can break down the test of your application into as many methods that you need, say one method that fills in a valid login name/password and that queries that it has moved to the next the page, one that tests login failure, enter an invalid email in the user field, did you app highlight that field/display it in red/display an alert with what is wrong. Another test method that logins with the correct user/pwd, which now you know works and now that you are on a new page, test all the features of that page. (Break each feature into a distinct test method if you want)

Comment: @SushiHangover But different test classes, would it be possible? Or just limited to methods?

Comment: If you want to break them into multiple classes (TestFixture) that is your choice, it makes sense if you need different SetUps, etc.. but in terms of chaining/sharing tests to avoid repeating (copy/pasting) code, it can add some overhead, but the choice is yours.

Comment: @SushiHangover Aryt, I guess I'll check it out. Thanks!